# clicking title bar fires onBlur in Opera

Tags: opera, titlebar, onblur

I am closing a popup window at 'onBlur' defined for 'BODY' of an ASP webpage, so when a user clicks outside the popup the popup closes. I want the popup to be moveable around the screen and it works for all browsers but Opera.

In Opera the 'onBlur' event is fired when clicking the titlebar of the popup - this seems weird for me, as the titlebar is a part of the popup window, right?

What can I do about it?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps close the popup from the parent window's onfocus instead?

I can confirm the problem based on this test:

javascript:void(window.open('data:text/html,window.onblur=window.close', '', 'width=100,height=100'));

Perhaps you could report a bug on https://bugs.opera.com/wizard/ ?